# What does $\text{Sym}(\mathfrak{g}[1])$ and $\mathfrak{g}[1])$ mean?

Tags: lie-algebras, homological-algebra

In Costello&Gwilliam's *Factorization ALgebras in Quantum Field Theory*, the Chevalley--Eilenberg complex of a module $M$ over a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with field $\mathbb{K}$ is defined as $\wedge g\otimes_\mathbb{K} M$ but at the same time, it is given by
$$C_*(\mathfrak{g},M)=(Sym(\mathfrak{g}[1])\otimes_K M, d)$$
What  does $\mathfrak{g}[1]$ mean and why is the Sym is there when we are considering the exterior algebra over $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: It's a suspension (degree shift).

Comment: @RicardoBuring Thanks! But could you tell me what that might be?

Answer (score 2):

If $V$ is a space in odd degree, then $\mathsf{Sym}(V)$ is actually exterior, in the sense $v\wedge w = - w\wedge v$ on generators (graded commutativity forces these signs to appear). If $V$ is graded, then $V[1]$ is the graded object with $V[1]_n = V_{n-1}$. So, if $\mathfrak g$ is a plain (non-dg) Lie algebra in degree zero (even), $\mathfrak g[1]$ is concentrated in degree one (as $\mathfrak g[1]_1 = \mathfrak g_0 = \mathfrak g$) and $\mathsf{Sym}(\mathfrak g[1])$ is just the exterior algebra on $\mathfrak g$ (with the catch that an element $v_1\wedge\cdots \wedge v_n$ is in homological degree $n$).